# Dynamic Cast working on unrelated types

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
class X{ 
     public: 
     virtual void f(){} 
}; 

class Y { 
     public: 
     virtual void g() {} 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
     X * x = new X(); 
     Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(x); //A 
     // Y* y = static_cast<Y*>(x);  //B 
     cout << y << endl; 
}
```

`A` compiles whereas `B` doesn't. I understand why `B` doesn't get compiled but why does `A` get compiled although `X` and `Y` are completely unrelated types?

Answer (score 24):

This is why `dynamic_cast` is allowed between unrelated types:

```
class X{ 
     public: 
     virtual void f(){} 
}; 

class Y { 
     public: 
     virtual void g() {} 
};

class Z : public X, public Y {};

int main()
{ 
     X* x = new Z(); 
     Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(x); // compiles and yields non-null pointer
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The dynamic cast uses the runtime type information. So this is legal do this case but it will return a null pointer.
The static cast is evaluated by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler doesn't care, because it is `dynamic_cast`. `y` will be `NULL` after the cast.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast` performs the type checking at runtime, using RTTI, while `static_cast` performs it at compile time. So what you'd get if you ran `A` would be `y == NULL`.

I suggest you [read up](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) on C++ type casts.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic cast returns NULL if it can't complete the cast:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

and search for dynamic_cast

Answer (score 1):

If [by using dynamic cast] you attempt to cast to a pointer type, and that type is not an actual type of the argument object, then the result of the cast will be **NULL**.

```
Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(x); // NULL because `X` is not a `Y`
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference between `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`, I'll just reduce the discussion to the objects world.

A `static_cast` may be used for the (infamous) up-cast. That is:

```
void foo(Base& b) { Derived& d = static_cast<Derived&>(b); }
```

The compiler can assess whether this is legal or not, because having the definition of `Derived` it **knows** whether or not `Derived` is actually a descendent of `Base`.

For non-trivial hierarchies:

```
struct Base {};
struct D1: Base {};
struct D2: Base {};
struct Derived: D1, D2 {};
```

This would yield an error: the compiler would not know from which of the bases (the one from `D1` or the one from `D2` you came from).

Or if you used `virtual` inheritance:

```
struct VDerived: virtual VBase {};
```

the compiler would need run-time information, and thus the compilation would fail too.

A `dynamic_cast` however is much more clever, though this comes at the cost of runtime-overhead. The compiler generates information about the objects generally know as RTTI (RunTime Type Information), that the `dynamic_cast` will explore to allow:

Cast depending on the true runtime type:

```
// will throw `bad_cast` if b is not a `Derived`
void foo(Base& b) { Derived& d = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(b); }
```

Cast accross branches:

```
struct X {};
struct Y {};

void foo(X* x) { Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(x); }

// If I add:
struct Z: X, Y {};

// then if x is in fact a Z, y will be non-null
```

Cast when there is virtual inheritance involved.

```
void bar(VBase* vb) { VDerived* vd = dynamic_cast<VDerived*>(vb); }
```

Cast to `void*` to get the true address of the object (this is somewhat special).

```
void foobar(X* x)
{
   void* xAddr = dynamic_cast<void*>(x);

   Y* y = dynamic_cast<Y*>(y);
   void* yAddr = dynamic_cast<void*>(y);

   Z* z = dynamic_cast<Z*>(x);
   void* zAddr = dynamic_cast<void*>(z);
   if (z) { assert(xAddr == yAddr && xAddr == zAddr); }
}
```

Note that this still doesn't work if there is an ambiguity because of the hierarchy (as with the `D1`/`D2` example above).